# This test seems to confirm accessing class variables is faster than method variables. Why?

Tags: c#, performance

So I wrote the following test code below just for kicks. I use VS 2017, have the framework version set to 4.7.2, and have the "optimize code" ticked when I compile for "Release".

Every time I run the code, the method that accesses the class variables runs faster than the method which has them as method variables.

I thought the latter would run faster since all that should be on the stack and not the heap.

**Is there something wrong with my test code? Or why would this be?**

static void Main(string[] args)
{

```
private static double _theClassVariableForTheMethodParameterVsClassVariableSpeedTest = 13.0;
private static int _numberOfComparisonsForTheMethodParameterVsClassVariableSpeedTest = 100;

    _numberOfComparisonsForTheMethodParameterVsClassVariableSpeedTest = 100;
    TestClassMemberVariableVsMethodParameterMethodParameter(_numberOfComparisonsForTheMethodParameterVsClassVariableSpeedTest, _theClassVariableForTheMethodParameterVsClassVariableSpeedTest);
    TestClassMemberVariableVsMethodParameterClassVariable();
    _numberOfComparisonsForTheMethodParameterVsClassVariableSpeedTest = 10000;
    TestClassMemberVariableVsMethodParameterMethodParameter(_numberOfComparisonsForTheMethodParameterVsClassVariableSpeedTest, _theClassVariableForTheMethodParameterVsClassVariableSpeedTest);
    TestClassMemberVariableVsMethodParameterClassVariable();
    _numberOfComparisonsForTheMethodParameterVsClassVariableSpeedTest = 1000000;
    TestClassMemberVariableVsMethodParameterMethodParameter(_numberOfComparisonsForTheMethodParameterVsClassVariableSpeedTest, _theClassVariableForTheMethodParameterVsClassVariableSpeedTest);
    TestClassMemberVariableVsMethodParameterClassVariable();
    _numberOfComparisonsForTheMethodParameterVsClassVariableSpeedTest = 100000000;
    TestClassMemberVariableVsMethodParameterMethodParameter(_numberOfComparisonsForTheMethodParameterVsClassVariableSpeedTest, _theClassVariableForTheMethodParameterVsClassVariableSpeedTest);
    TestClassMemberVariableVsMethodParameterClassVariable();
```

}

```
#region ClassMemberVariableVsMethodParameter
static void TestClassMemberVariableVsMethodParameterMethodParameter(int numberOfComparisons, double theMethodParamNumber)
{
    Console.WriteLine("######## " + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Number of comparisons: " + numberOfComparisons.ToString("#,##0"));

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    double totalSum = 0;

    Thread.Sleep(500);
    Console.WriteLine("###########################################################");
    Console.WriteLine("Starting MethodParameterAccess test with " + numberOfComparisons.ToString("#,##0") + " at: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    sw.Restart();
    for (int x = 0; x < numberOfComparisons; x++)
    {
        totalSum += theMethodParamNumber;
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Finished at: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    Console.WriteLine("Time to run: " + sw.Elapsed.ToString("mm\\:ss\\.fffffff"));
    Console.WriteLine("Sum is: " + totalSum.ToString("#,##0"));

    Thread.Sleep(500);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
static void TestClassMemberVariableVsMethodParameterClassVariable()
{
    Console.WriteLine("######## " + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Number of comparisons: " + _numberOfComparisonsForTheMethodParameterVsClassVariableSpeedTest.ToString("#,##0"));

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    double totalSum = 0;

    Thread.Sleep(500);
    Console.WriteLine("###########################################################");
    Console.WriteLine("Starting Class Variable Access test with " + _numberOfComparisonsForTheMethodParameterVsClassVariableSpeedTest.ToString("#,##0") + " at: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    sw.Restart();
    for (int x = 0; x < _numberOfComparisonsForTheMethodParameterVsClassVariableSpeedTest; x++)
    {
        totalSum += _theClassVariableForTheMethodParameterVsClassVariableSpeedTest;
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Finished at: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    Console.WriteLine("Time to run: " + sw.Elapsed.ToString("mm\\:ss\\.fffffff"));
    Console.WriteLine("Sum is: " + totalSum.ToString("#,##0"));

    Thread.Sleep(500);
    Console.WriteLine();
}

#endregion
```

Here's sample results from one of the runs I've done. Notice all the method calls with parameters runs slower than those that reference class variables. I've done this about half a dozen times and all the runs have similar results:

> ## TestClassMemberVariableVsMethodParameterMethodParameter Number of comparisons: 100
>   
>   ##################################################### Starting MethodParameterAccess test with 100 at: 7:51:44 PM Finished at:
>
> 7:51:44 PM Time to run: 00:00.0000026 Sum is: 1,300
>
> ## TestClassMemberVariableVsMethodParameterClassVariable Number of comparisons: 100
>   
>   ##################################################### Starting Class Variable Access test with 100 at: 7:51:45 PM Finished at:
>
> 7:51:45 PM Time to run: 00:00.0000005 Sum is: 1,300
>
> ## TestClassMemberVariableVsMethodParameterMethodParameter Number of comparisons: 10,000
>   
>   ##################################################### Starting MethodParameterAccess test with 10,000 at: 7:51:46 PM Finished at:
>
> 7:51:46 PM Time to run: 00:00.0000285 Sum is: 130,000
>
> ## TestClassMemberVariableVsMethodParameterClassVariable Number of comparisons: 10,000
>   
>   ##################################################### Starting Class Variable Access test with 10,000 at: 7:51:47 PM Finished at:
>
> 7:51:47 PM Time to run: 00:00.0000276 Sum is: 130,000
>
> ## TestClassMemberVariableVsMethodParameterMethodParameter Number of comparisons: 1,000,000
>   
>   ##################################################### Starting MethodParameterAccess test with 1,000,000 at: 7:51:48 PM Finished at:
>
> 7:51:48 PM Time to run: 00:00.0034285 Sum is: 13,000,000
>
> ## TestClassMemberVariableVsMethodParameterClassVariable Number of comparisons: 1,000,000
>   
>   ##################################################### Starting Class Variable Access test with 1,000,000 at: 7:51:49 PM Finished at:
>
> 7:51:49 PM Time to run: 00:00.0028730 Sum is: 13,000,000
>
> ## TestClassMemberVariableVsMethodParameterMethodParameter Number of comparisons: 100,000,000
>   
>   ##################################################### Starting MethodParameterAccess test with 100,000,000 at: 7:51:50 PM Finished
>
> at: 7:51:50 PM Time to run: 00:00.3210571 Sum is: 1,300,000,000
>
> ## TestClassMemberVariableVsMethodParameterClassVariable Number of comparisons: 100,000,000
>   
>   ##################################################### Starting Class Variable Access test with 100,000,000 at: 7:51:51 PM Finished
>
> at: 7:51:51 PM Time to run: 00:00.3205412 Sum is: 1,300,000,000

Comment: The differences are small enough to be noise. Try doing this with [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/).

Comment: I don't care about noise.I want to understand why - that's why StackOverFlow is for. Thank you for your suggestion on BenchmarkDotNet.

Comment: When I ran the code I continuously got mixed results whether I compiled for 32 or x64. Not as lop sided as yours with the heap method (the one that references the class variables) always our performing the stack method (the one using parameters) but still... the mixed bag is fascinating.